# JavaScript Validation/Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need to apply validation to a text box of condition 
expression that expression is in one of the following formats.

```
Valid Inputs:- 
1) (C1 && C2) || (C1 || C3)
2) (C1 || C3)
3)  C1
4) (C1 && C2) || C3   ...etc.

Invalid Inputs:-
1) (C1 && C2
2) (C1 || ) C2
3) C1 && C2     ...etc.
```

Points to take care:

1. There could be && or || operators only in Condition expression.
2. There could be any number of conditions C1, C2, C3, C4.....so on.
3. opening and closing brackets should match and in each bracket, there should be two conditions separated by && or || operator.
4. Only `()` brackets will be used in the expression.

How can I do this is there any javascript regular expression available for this? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you tried so far...

Comment: not a meaningful question.

Comment: I would split it into a tree structure and iterate over the tree

Comment: Regex isn't best tool for such tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the solution!

Actually, I wanted to evaluate the above logical operator expression, where each C1, C2 ...Cn will be replaced by either true or false in API side and will be evaluated using javax.script.ScriptEngine.eval() so in this case I want to validate the expression on UI side.

So , to validate it I just used the `eval()` of javascript in which I'll pass the condition expression by replacing C1 , C2 ... Cn by either true or false (just to check whether the expression is syntactically correct or not).

e.g

(C1 && C2) && (C3 || C4)

To check the above expression for syntax I just replaced the C1 ,C2 , C3 and C4 with boolean values like "(true && true) && (true || true)" and tested it using

```
eval("(true && true) && (true || true)")
```

if there is no => 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input' error means the expression is valid. This works for me.

Thanks